# Why does spray-can server not respond to a http request?

Tags: scala, spray

I'm trying to set a very basic HTTP server using [spray-can](https://github.com/spray/spray-can). If I call the endpoint I've set a mapping for, I'm getting a timeout (although using a debugger I can see that the actor receives the message).

My source looks like this:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.IO
import spray.can.Http
import spray.http.{HttpMethods, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Uri}

class App extends Actor {

  implicit val system = context.system

  override def receive = {
    case "start" =>
      val listener: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[HttpListener])
      IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(listener, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
  }

}

class HttpListener extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case _: Http.Connected =>
      sender() ! Http.Register(self)
    case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/ping"), _, _, _) =>
      HttpResponse(entity = "PONG")
  }

}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("my-actor-system")
    val app: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[App], "app")
    app ! "start"
  }

}
```

Executing `run` shows:

```
> run
[info] Running Main
[INFO] [09/10/2014 21:33:38.839] [my-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://my-actor-system/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
```

The following `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` shows up when I hit `http://localhost:8080/ping`:

```
➜  ~  curl --include http://localhost:8080/ping
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: spray-can/1.3.1
Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 19:34:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 111

Ooops! The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request.
Please try again in a short while!
```

My `build.sbt` looks like:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % "1.3.1",
  "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % "1.3.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.5"
)
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/ping"), _, _, _) =>
  HttpResponse(entity = "PONG")
```

should be

```
case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, Uri.Path("/ping"), _, _, _) =>
  sender ! HttpResponse(entity = "PONG")
```

You are returning HttpResponse instead of sending a message to the sender.

Comment: I don't understand why Scala compiler did not complain that HttpResponse was returned when Unit was expected.

Comment: Ravi - Scala performs an implicit conversion from any value to Unit when the expected type is Unit. -- From the spec: Value Discarding. If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is not good. I guess `-Ywarn-value-discard` should become a standard flag in all my sbts from now on.